# Multiple requests to same resources when using multiple +1 and "Like" buttons

Tags: html, share, http-request

My site is http://fridgecow.com. Thanks to the blog I recently installed to the front page, I now have over 100 HTTP requests, and most of them to the same site. I have done all I can on my side (sprited, condensed, etc) but still I end up with a massive load time.

Is there any "Share" buttons that get round this problem (maybe with an "href" attribute)?

Comment: You might be able to make the request through Javascript, and force the image to be loaded just once.  But then it would require Javascript.  It seems like if you have duplicate resources, the browser/server should be smart enough to figure out not to make duplicate requests.

Answer (score 0):

combine css files into single css file and js files into single js file.

Or

you can use these two sites, they will combine your css and js files

http://www.boxjs.com/ 
http://www.boxcss.com/

you do some thing like this on your site and they will combine files for you

```
<script src="http://www.boxjs.com/box.js"></script>
Box('http://mywebsite.com/scripts/', [
        'plugins/jquery.js',
        'plugins/json2.js',
        'plugins/jquery-class.js'
]);
```

similar for css

or write your own code that performs the following

- do not request all your css/js file on top or bottom rather load only those files that are neccessary at the beginning.
- rather create a javascript file that loads each file one after other in sequential order.

There are many strategies that you may choose

Comment: This is not what I asked! Look at the site and you'll see what I mean. (the "blog" div to the right)